# Why does json.dumps change the casing of boolean value?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I've been using `json.dumps()` to create some templates but when using it, it changes the casing of my boolean values
Here's how to replicate:

```
import json

test_obj = {'field': False}
print json.dumps(test_obj)
# prints {"field": false}
```

What's the reason for this?

Comment: Might have to do with it being lowercase is Javascript, and therefore maybe lowercase by the JSON spec?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I actually was about to edit and write that as a suggestion! That would make a lot of sense.

Comment: @kermitvomit Regardless, that must be just a string representation. It shouldn't actually effect anything unless you try to `eval` what `dumps` gives you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json.dumps()` converts a Python dictionary to a JSON object formatted as a string. According to the [JSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), the two boolean literals in JSON are `true` and `false`. So, `json.dumps()` isn't changing the casing, it's only converting Python's boolean literals, `True` and `False`, to JSON's boolean literals, `true` and `false`, respectively.

If you do wish to get a string representation of the Python dictionary without converting to JSON, you could cast the dictionary to string using `str()`

Answer (score 0):

JSON stands for `JavaScript Object Notation` and `true` is boolean representation in JS. Compare with [these docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders).